# TS Interface with variable vs with params of function

Tags: typescript

I am a bit confused about how TS validates **`Interface`** for **variable vs params of function**

**What I am not getting is,**

why `function` `param` is behaving like optional fields, I can pass one or two fields from `Interface` type even if it has five,

But when we use it with `variable` we must need to provide five of them.

```
interface Vehicle {
    brand: string;
    summary: (message : string) => string;
}

const vehicle: Vehicle = {
    name : 'civic', // <------------- Throws Error here
    summary : (message: string) => {
        console.log(message);
        return message;
    }
}

function callme (param : Vehicle) { // <------------- But no any error here
    param.summary('Checking');
}

callme(vehicle);
```

**[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGxQbwFgAoZM5AIyjhABMAuZAZzClAHMBuE85gVwC2AuFACejABQCITJnHYpGLNiHYBKZAF4AfM1YduxAL4kSCAPYgWyAG6ZseRuiy4Um5EVLkQcackYA5AjANtgBADQ85EyCwmL+yFIycgpK+qoaOh5RvGQWVuZ4AHQ45uxJsvIQaoa55FAQYHxQIMjSlQq15CbGpsQwfCAIYMCWyAhwODh+EgAOIr4Jzg7V2V5k89QCRTFCIqISAQDCGBAIANYcATUkPWaT0xASdi54NUA)**

I couldn't find any documentation or article that can justify the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error because that is a valid function signature, it accepts arguments of type `Vehicle`. Similarly, when you call it, you are calling it with `vehicle` which you asserted to be of type `Vehicle`. The types match, so typescript doesn't show any error.

The only error you're seeing it is when you're trying to initialise `vehicle` as a `Vehicle` type. since `Vehicle` doesn't have a `name` property, typescript is showing you an error.

Furthermore, `vehicle` can be cast to a `Vehicle` type because the type of `summary` property matches and the extra parameters can be ignored. That's why you could remove the typing (`const vehicleUntyped = { ... }`) and still not get an error.

But you would see an error if your `vehicle` had a type which couldn't be assigned to `Vehicle`, for instance if `summary` had a different signature, e.g. a number (`vehicleUnassignable = { summary: 5 }`).

### Example

```
const vehicleUntyped = {
    name : 'civic',
    summary : (message: string) => {
        console.log(message);
        return message;
    }
}

callme(vehicleUntyped); // ✅ param can be cast to Vehicle

const vehicleUnassignable = {
    summary: 5
}

callme(vehicleUnassignable); // ❌ type mismach, error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGxQbwFgAoZM5AZwFcBbGuKATwC5kAKGiCiuAcxVYUwUULwCUyALwA+SsNEkAviRIIA9iCHIAbpmx5W6LLhSTkRUuRBxOyVgHIEwbdnsAaEuUq16TO+05uPghBeRBxKVkLLy91TTU8ADocNV4OLh5+MQBuTxiyKAgwKigQZEDMiFzLMmViOpIYKhAEMGANZAQ4HBxbNgAHBht-I30ICWjyQagbROo6BkY2ewBhDAgEAGtRexylFWIuns42XWM8PeJVDS0zsYBVcEZ+iAATKXM8smtbBycXBDuL7eBZ+VjpIL8UIicISGSfGoxOIUBIQZKpCGVS75ApFEplCrBapeOoNQ7dXoQU56EyPMDPN6Xa6aMA6Gl4R5wbjAXjWABGeA+kzI818LGQAFZ9ldyccqXdadZuby4ALxtkgA)

Comment: But `name` is missing when I am passing to function param as well. then why it's not throwing error, at the end param is also type of `Vehicle`?

Comment: you mean why there's no error when you declare the function? that is just a signature, you're saying it accept a `Vehicle` type. when you try to use this function with a param that doesn't match `Vehicle`, that's when you'll get an error.

Comment: see my edit about casting also

Comment: Yes, I got all your points, sorry for the confusion, the only thing I am not getting is, why function param is behaving like optional fields, I can pass one or two fields from Interface type even if it has five, but when I use it with variable you must needs to provide five of them.

Comment: Upvoted answer, because you put your efforts :)